# Spring + Hibernate + Maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, gwt, jpa-2.0

I'm deploying war to tomcat. Maven scope is set to "compile". War contains all required jars, including "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final".

When i run tomcat, i get:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
```

I'm using spring4gwt. I don't get how java could not find class, that is included in lib folder in WEB-INF in WAR archive.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show the pom file?

Comment: I have resolved the problem by not using gwt-maven-plugin.